# Checking if singly-linked list is palindrome or not

Tags: c#, linked-list, singly-linked-list, palindrome

This is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LinkedList
{
    public class Node
    {
        public int data;
        public Node next;
        public Node(int data)
        {
            this.data = data;
            next = null;
        }
    }

    public class MyList
    {
        public Node head;

        public MyList()
        {
            head = null;
        }

        public void addNode(int data)
        {
            if(head == null)
            {
                head = new Node(data);

            }
            else
            {
                Node temp = new Node(data);              

                Node current = head;
                while(current.next != null)
                {
                    current = current.next;
                }
                current.next = temp;
            }
        }

        public void print()
        {
            if(head == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("List is already empty!");
            }
            else
            {
                Node current = head;
                while (current != null)
                {
                    Console.Write("|" + current.data + "|-> ");
                    current = current.next;
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        public void addToStart(int data)
        {
            if(head == null)
            {
                head = new Node(data);
            }
            else
            {
                Node temp = new Node(data);
                temp.next = head;
                head = temp;
            }
        }

        public void addSorted(int data)
        {
            if(head == null)
            {
                head = new Node(data);
            }
            else if(data < head.data)
            {
                addToStart(data);
            }
            else
            {
                Node current = head.next;
                Node previous = head;
                Node temp = new Node(data);

                while(current != null)
                {
                    if(data < current.data)
                    {
                        previous.next = temp;
                        temp.next = current;
                        break;
                    }
                    previous = current;
                    current = current.next;
                }
            }
        }

        public void removeLast()
        {
            if(head == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("List is already empty!");
            }
            else if(head.next == null)
            {
                head = null;
            }
            else
            {
                Node current = head.next;
                Node previous = head;

                while(current.next != null)
                {
                    previous = current;
                    current = current.next;
                }
                previous.next = null;
            }
        }

        public bool isPalindrome()
        {
            List<int> arr1 = new List<int>();
            int i = 0;
            Node current = head;

            while (current != null)
            {
                arr1.Add(current.data);
                current = current.next;
                i++;
            }

            int[] arr3 = arr1.ToArray();
            int count = i;
            int[] arr2 = new int[count];
            int j = 0;

            for (int x = i - 1; x >= 0; x--)
            {
                arr2[j] = arr3[x];
            }

            for (int k = 0; k < count; k++)
            {
                if (arr3[k] != arr2[k])
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyList a = new MyList();
            a.addNode(1);
            a.addNode(2);
            a.addNode(5);
            a.addNode(2);
            a.addNode(1);
            a.print();

            if(a.isPalindrome())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Linked List is Palindrome!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Linked List is Not Palindrome!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My code returns false for the palindrome function every time except when I enter only one value in the linked list.

Also let me know if my method of `List<int>` is okay or not because I needed it for the palindrome check.

Comment: You realize that you're *less* likely to receive an answer when you try to be more important by putting your title in all caps, right? Guess what, you're question isn't more important than anyone else's.

Comment: So, what does your debugger say the values of `arr2` and `arr3` are, and how do they compare with the input list? Have you stepped through the code in the debugger to watch it live?

Comment: FWIW, I suspect you got all those down-votes for the yelling in the title. The presentation of the question itself is not half-bad, better than many questions we see from newbies around here. At least there's an actual [mcve]. I do think you should spend more time with a debugger; The previous comment from @Ken is giving you a big hint as to where to look. As for the question of the actual implementation, I think using `List<T>` is overkill; why not just count and then copy straight into an array? Alternatively, you could write a recursive method to check without using any intermediate objects

Comment: @itsme86 thanks for the advice. I didnt knw that we could find people like you here at stack overflow too. -_-

Comment: @KenY-N I've tried with the debugger too but its doesn't say anything. Its been a while for me in C#. I shifted to android and now i'm facing problems in getting back.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I'll try what you said about the count and and then making an array instead of a List<t>.

Comment: On a serious note, I'll try not to use caps again. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankyou for your comments, This is how i solved it.

```
public bool isPalindrome()
    {
        int i = 0;
        Node current = head;
        Node temp = head;

        while (temp != null)
        {
            temp = temp.next;
            i++;
        }

        int[] arr1 = new int[i];
        int count = i;

        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
        {
            arr1[j] = current.data;
            current = current.next;
        }

        int[] arr2 = new int[count];
        int z = 0;

        for (int x = i - 1; x >= 0; x--)
        {
            arr2[z] = arr1[x];
            z++;
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < count; x++)
        {
            if (arr1[x] != arr2[x])
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```